# Defining a Discrete Probability Distribution in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, distribution

I have been trying to create my own discrete distribution in Visual Studio (C++). I kept getting the same error. I then tried the example code from: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution/.

Again, the same error appeared with this example code.

The line of code (from the link) that is giving me an error is:

```
std::discrete_distribution second(init.begin(), init.end());
```

Particularly, `init.begin()` is underlined in red.

The 2 errors are as follows:

```
error C2661: 'std::discrete_distribution::discrete_distribution' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::discrete_distribution<_Ty>::discrete_distribution [with _Ty=int]" matches the argument list argument types are: (std::_Array_iterator, std::_Array_iterator)
```

Why would my compiler not work? I am wondering if other people are getting the same errors? I also just updated my version of Visual Studio to make sure it wasn't an old bug

Comment: [Known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/976256/discrete-distribution-inputiterator-first-inputiterator-last-couldnt-compile). If you believe the VC team, it's impossible to fix bugs in updates, so you'll need to install VS2015 to (hopefully) get the fix.

Comment: @Praetorian But there is no express edition for VS2015 and I can't afford to pay for regular edition.

Comment: @Praetorian true that. I came to discover a *horrible* bug in the VS2010 regex implementation that did not match sequence counted captures because of an off-by-one bug. I (and a ton of other people) were *livid* when the official response from MS was : it looks like its fixed in the VS2013 beta so once that is released, use that (and then closed the ticket). Pffft.!!

Comment: @WhozCraig I just deleted by VS express 2013 and downloaded VS Community 2015. Voila! The problem is fixed!

Answer (score 3):

The problem was due to a bug in VS express 2013. By installing VS Community 2015, the error message vanished.