# C++ compilation error in discrete_distribution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

I am getting a compile error in the lines below, which i dont fully understand.
according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8c8ba8f8-c06f-4f07-b354-f53950142fcf.aspx) the syntax is correct.

```
vector<int> temp_weights = //some data will be here

discrete_distribution<int> weights ({ temp_weights.begin(), temp_weights.end() }); //error C2440
```

the full error is:

```
Error   5   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'std::discrete_distribution<int>'
```

Comment: Please note your full compiler version.

Comment: @tambre: it is Visual Studio C++ 2013 Update 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`discrete_distribution<int> weights { temp_weights.begin(), temp_weights.end() };`

The reason this doesn't work is because it's the syntax for an initialization list,
the compiler thinks you want to store `temp_weights.begin()` at `weights[0]` and
`temp_weights.end()` at `weights[1]`.

There should be a constructor that accepts two `vector::iterator`'s (in order to copy the vectors elements across), and so this should work for you

`discrete_distribution<int> weights ( temp_weights.begin(), temp_weights.end() );`

Comment: thx, but it seems there is no such constructor in my version of <random> since then i get the error: `Error 5 error C2661: 'std::discrete_distribution<int>::discrete_distribution' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments`

Comment: Unfortunately that error's likely due to a bug in your version of vs2013 [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175655/defining-a-discrete-probability-distribution-in-c)